# How to select item in combobox by value, not by index

Tags: excel, vba

I have values in combobox like 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu'... in column 1.

Each value have its Id in bound column 2.

The question is, how can I select item by value in column 1 or column 2, not by index (record count dynamically varies).

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To Me.ComboBox1.ListCount - 1 Step 1

    If Me.ComboBox1.List(i, 0) = "SOMEVALUE" Then 'looks in column 1, change the 0 to 1 for column 2

        MsgBox "ITEM FOUND"
    End If
Next i
```